# Displaying SPChange data in visual webpart

Tags: list-view, visual-web-part, changelog

Here is some code I've been playing with to display all items that have been changed in a web and all subwebs in a visual webpart (it grabs a heap of info and chucks it in a label):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ChangeLog = "";

        SPChangeQuery query = new SPChangeQuery(false,false);
        query.Add = true; query.Update = true; query.Delete = true;
        query.File = true; query.Item = true;

        SPChangeCollection CurrentSiteChanges = SPContext.Current.Site.GetChanges(query);

        foreach(SPChange Change in CurrentSiteChanges)
        {
            if (Change.GetType() == typeof(SPChangeItem))
            {
                SPChangeItem ChangeItem = Change as SPChangeItem;
                using (SPWeb Web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(ChangeItem.WebId))
                {
                    foreach (SPWeb ChildWeb in SPContext.Current.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
                    {
                        SPFile Item = Web.GetFile(ChangeItem.UniqueId);
                        if (Item.Exists)
                        {
                            /*
                            ChangeLog += "File: <a href='" + Item.Url + "'>" + Item.Name + "</a> @ " + ChangeItem.Time.ToString() + " | Site: " + Web.Title + "<br />";
                             */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lbl_Webs.Text = ChangeLog;
    }
```

I want to know how I can place the info in the commented section of the code above into a control that displays items like other webparts usually do (don't know what this control will be, a ListView or something). Can anybody advise how to do this, or suggest an alternative if I'm doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTable and SPGridView combo.

Define the SPGridView in the markup like below:-

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="spgvChangeLists" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <SharePoint:SPBoundField DataField="Site" HeaderText="Site" />
    <SharePoint:SPBoundField DataField="TimeChange" HeaderText="Change Time" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlFileLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ItemUrl")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <strong>There are no changes/strong>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

And in the code behind define the DataTable, get the changes data and bind it to the spgridview like below:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemName");
        dt.Columns.Add("ItemUrl");
        dt.Columns.Add("TimeChange");
        dt.Columns.Add("Site");

        SPChangeQuery query = new SPChangeQuery(false, false);
        query.Add = true; query.Update = true; query.Delete = true;
        query.File = true; query.Item = true;

        SPChangeCollection CurrentSiteChanges = SPContext.Current.Site.GetChanges(query);

        foreach (SPChange Change in CurrentSiteChanges)
        {
            if (Change.GetType() == typeof(SPChangeItem))
            {
                SPChangeItem ChangeItem = Change as SPChangeItem;
                using (SPWeb Web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(ChangeItem.WebId))
                {
                    foreach (SPWeb ChildWeb in SPContext.Current.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
                    {
                        SPFile Item = Web.GetFile(ChangeItem.UniqueId);
                        if (Item.Exists)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                            dr["ItemUrl"] = Item.Url;
                            dr["ItemName"] = Item.Name;
                            dr["TimeChange"] = ChangeItem.Time.ToString();
                            dr["Site"] = Web.Title;

                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        spgvChangeLists.DataSource = dt;
        spgvChangeLists.DataBind();
    }
```

If you want sorting, paging and filtering functionality without writing any code, you can use ObjectDataSource + DataTable + SPGridView or LinqDataSource + Custom Objects + SPGridView
Hope this helps